# How to read Values from Request.form.Allkeys

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

I have checkboxes that I have created using Literal now on postback I get the checkboxes which are checked in the `Request.form.Allkeys`. However I don't know how to read those values how can I use them? how can I count how many values are in there and how can I find some values in there example I want to find if the `request.forum.allkey` contain `forumaName0` ..

thank you

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have these checkboxes in your aspx page:

```
<input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="forumaName0" />
<input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="forumaName1" />
<input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="forumaName2" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

You should be able to iterate through all the keys and check if the desired checkbox is checked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        Response.Write(key + "<br />");
    }

    Response.Write("Contain forumaName0? - " + Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("forumaName0"));
}
```

EDIT - Screenshot for downvoter:
[image]

Comment: Test the code out before downvote and make any negative comment. See EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

A quick FYI, in regards to the `Contains` method mentioned by Lee Sy En and AsifQadri: make sure you have `System.Linq` in your assembly references if you want to use it (or any of the other `IEnumerable` extension methods shown in the screenshot above).